# Which one of these words can describe pizzas and sandwiches?

Tags: word-choice

I'm an order taker so when someone asked me: "What's inside this sandwich?" or "What's on this Pizza?", can I use following words for the description (regardless if they are verbs or nouns):

- has components (of *x*, *y* and *z*)
- does contain (*x*, *y* and *z*)
- consists of (*x*, *y* and *z*)
- is made out of the ingredients (*x*, *y* and *z*)

**Note:**
The sandwich is cooked and ready to eat, so they don't ask about the ingredients of the bread itself (like salt, flour, yeast, etc.)

Do you have any other words that you would like to suggest to add to my vocabulary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't disagree with Michael's answer, but I think you could shorten it further & keep your wording consistent.

As said, a sandwich has a filling, a pizza has a topping [except calzone]

> "What inside this sandwich?"

"The sandwich has bacon, lettuce and tomato."

> "What's on this Pizza?"

"The pizza has cheese, pepperoni and mushrooms."

You wouldn't really need to specify in or on, topping or filling - the customer already knows *where* it will be, they just want to know *what* it will be.

You could abbreviate it even more if the customer was only asking one of the questions, not both...

> "What's on this Pizza?"

"Cheese, pepperoni and mushrooms."

A native wouldn't waste energy by re-stating any of the question in the answer if it wasn't necessary. They would use context alone.

Answer (score 0):

A sandwich has a filling. A pizza has a topping. This sandwich's filling is (or consists of -rather bookish) ham, cheese and onion. This pizza's topping is/consists of tomatoes, anchovies, mushrooms, and cheese. A sandwich or pizza order taker would usually say a filling or topping 'is' rather than 'consists of' (whatever). There is a type of folded pizza, called a calzone, and in this case the 'topping' on the baked sheet of dough could be called a filling. It's simpler in Italian, where the added ingredients are called *condimenti* for either type.

Comment: You can actually have a pizza with a filling: https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=4msMW4bENdKQmgXdtqTYDA&q=calzone+pizza&oq=calzone+&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.1.1.41j0i67l2j0l3.6508.8819..11023...0....127.870.2j6......0....1.......3..0i131.ztkWINefiPQ%3D#imgrc=iDhVhWbWJP6elM:

Comment: You mean a calzone. Anglos think of pizzas as flat things. The OP described being asked "What's **on** this pizza?"

Comment: Yes, but the are variants, and calzone or rolls have fillings

Comment: I would go with is and forget consists.

Comment: **Au contraire:** the word *condimento" does not mean the fillings, toppings or components of a dish, but rather dressings and sauces like ketchup, mustard, BBQ sauce, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condiment & https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condimento

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach - I condimenti della pizza sono le farciture della pizza su cui gli ingredienti vengono posti sull'impasto prima, durante o dopo la cottura.

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach - _condimenti_ in the context of _le pizze_ are what Gringos, Anglos, etc, call 'toppings'. Yes, they are 'seasonings' (see the verb _condire_ ) _Come condire la pizza? ... Se invece è il pomodoro a crearvi problemi, il condimento ai quattro formaggi è l’ideale._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/condire: 1. to flavour/flavor or season (food)
2. to dress (a salad)
3. (figurative) to spice up, to embellish
...
So pasta is a condiment as well, because "gringos" are putting it on a pizza as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. The noun `component` should get used when referring to single dishes in a whole menu, as it in general means [self sustaining parts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/component) of an system, e.g. a pump of a washing machine.
2. The verb `to contain` is completely valid: The subject is in every case the whole dish as it gets ordered. So you do not need to worry it actually is a `filling`, `topping` or "pre-cooked ingredients". Also you can use it subjunctive while listing all relevant allergens. It is even comprehensive enough to refer to a skewer holding everything in place ;)
3. The same goes for the verb `to consist` as well, but as it is exhaustive you would make the claim that your answer will include **every** ingredient used, so I would personally try to avoid it in the context of food if i do not want to either pass a recipe nor to act specifically degrading: "The so called "loaf" consisted of a gooey substance which tasted and smelled disgustingly"

You could use many unusual words in a metaphorical way as well, be a bit  exaggerating and say "this delicious art was composed of ... "